# Unable to make azure continuous integration build pipeline due to Execution failed for task':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am using "react-native": "0.62.2" and my gradle settings look like,

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
glideVersion = "4.9.0"
kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

I have issues while building the project on azure CI pipeline

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not determine artifacts for com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.9.0: Skipped due to earlier error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Please help me to fix this issue.

My Configuration  as below

```
  pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - yarn
  - java

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@3
  displayName: 'Install NPM modules'

- bash: 'echo "Hello"'
  displayName: 'Configure Gradle'
  enabled: false

- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: gradle
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: android/gradlew
    workingDirectory: android
    options: '--warning-mode=all '
    publishJUnitResults: false
    jdkVersionOption: 1.11
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3g -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  displayName: 'Signing and aligning APK file(s) **/*.apk'
  inputs:
    apksignerKeystoreFile: '8bf9f45a-cbc3-4c97-987b-c10611c07aca'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: 123456
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'my-key-alias'
    apksignerKeyPassword: 123456
    zipalign: false
  enabled: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
```

Comment: Please share with us your pipeline configuration.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I edited the questions and adding the Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue I changed my way in building the pipieline

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands: yarn

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@3
  displayName: 'Install NPM modules'

- task: BatchScript@1
  displayName: 'Run script android/gradlew.bat app:assembleRelease'
  inputs:
    filename: 'android/gradlew.bat app:assembleRelease'
  enabled: false

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'clean '
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./android/gradlew
    arguments: clean
    workingDirectory: android

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'assembleRelease '
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./android/gradlew
    arguments: 'assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'
    workingDirectory: android

- bash: 'echo "Hello"'
  displayName: 'Configure Gradle'
  enabled: false

- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: gradle
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: android/gradlew
    workingDirectory: android
    options: '--warning-mode=all '
    publishJUnitResults: false
    jdkVersionOption: 1.11
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3g -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
  enabled: false

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  displayName: 'Signing and aligning APK file(s) **/*.apk'
  inputs:
    apksignerKeystoreFile: '8bf9f45a-cbc3-4c97-987b-c10611c07aca'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: 123456
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'my-key-alias'
    apksignerKeyPassword: 123456
    zipalign: false
  enabled: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
```